# Is there any place to see online users and statistics about gis.SE?

Tags: discussion

i am really wonder -`I could not find how much I look`- if there is any place to see online users and getting total number of online users.

Beside this can we see any report about community as daily, monthly, weekly, annual users numbers, questions, answers and tags as User Reputation League.

i think similar to this report can give us trends about gis world...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Online Data & Queries

Monthly statistics are available for the entire Stack Exchange network, see the [[data]](http://data.stackexchange.com/) link at bottom of every page. The gateway of pre-built reports for our little corner is http://data.stackexchange.com/gis/queries, which includes things like

- The [top 50 most prolific editors](http://data.stackexchange.com/gis/query/6627/top-50-most-prolific-editors),
- High Standards - [Top 100 Users that rarely upvote](http://data.stackexchange.com/gis/query/6856/high-standards-top-100-users-that-rarely-upvote),
- [Users by Popular Question ratio](http://data.stackexchange.com/gis/query/2777/users-by-popular-question-ratio)

All of the queries can be customized and saved and shared separately. There is an online [query editor](http://data.stackexchange.com/gis/query/new) to help build them. The query results are downloadable in CSV for analysing in other programs.

*Caveat emptor* on the queries by the way, [true unsung heroes](http://data.stackexchange.com/gis/query/6607/the-true-unsung-heros) only lists [underdark](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/187/underdark), one of our strongest and most recognized pillars! ;-)

There is a also a torrent download of the whole network data directly via [Stack Exchange Data Dump](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump); updated every 3 months. There is mention of Open Data Endpoints ([OData](http://www.odata.org/)) in the [About data page](http://data.stackexchange.com/about), but I don't know what that is about.

### API

As of February 2012, [v2.0](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchange-api-v2-0-no-longer-beta/) of the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/) is published and available for general use. A good way to keep abreast of major developments in this space is to watch the [API tag on the SO Blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/api/).

[Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com) is a site dedicated to applications built using the api. Two apps of note for our community is the [Stackmaps](https://stackapps.com/questions/3367/stackmaps-interactive-maps-of-stack-exchange-communities) mashup courtesy of @johndbritton showing user location, and [Stack Geography](https://stackapps.com/questions/2913/stackgeography-a-stack-exchange-question-mapping-site) by @partridge which shows the location of by questions asked.

Also [Mathematica.se](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) site has some examples of [using the SE api for statistical graphs](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301/how-are-we-doing-post-your-favorite-stats) (thanks @whuber).

[image: GIS.se users on Stackmaps]

[image: GIS.se questions on Stack Geography]

Comment: +1 You have reminded me that users *can* get a lot of this information through the SE API.  Visit http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/301/how-are-we-doing-post-your-favorite-stats for examples.

Comment: thank you @matt, it couldnt have been better as an answer. i will check out your link for getting some information...

Comment: Thanks @whuber, I folded the API examples into in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for your interest and concern!  Moderators have access to this information, in the form of customizable graphs of the expected daily data (visitors, questions asked, answers supplied, etc.), *provided* we do not share details.  We can use this, I presume, to respond generally to specific questions such as "is this site growing," "is site usage correlated with academic calendars," and so on, so consider asking such specific questions if you like.

In my opinion, site usage data tell us almost nothing about the GIS world, because how we are doing as a community depends on so many more variables than the popularity of GIS in general.  If anything, it is most closely related to how well we are letting people know of our existence and potential usefulness.  One thing we can do as individuals is to promulgate that information: tell your friends about us! Put links into social media, email messages, and Web pages you control.  (The site tracks links if they include your user id and awards badges--[Announcer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/badges/59/announcer), [Booster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/badges/60/booster), and [Publicist](https://gis.stackexchange.com/badges/61/publicist)--for such activity.)  Please let us know of any other suggestions you might have for growing and improving our site.

Answer (score 1):

To get to one of the specific questions you asked, what is the total number of users, I think the answer is thus:

```
select
  Count(Users.Id) as [Number of Users]
From
  Users
```

Run it here: http://data.stackexchange.com/gis/query/73632/total-number-of-users

I tried extending it to "number of users seen today", but haven't been able to figure out the syntax. It might resemble something like:

```
Count(Users.LastAccessDate == GETDATE()) as [Seen Today]
```

or perhaps

```
Count(Users.LastAccessDate >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())) as [Seen Today]
```

(the `dateadd` and `getdate` keywords cribbed from other examples I found on the site.)

Comment: Ahhh, the data explorer is old data (up to 30 days or so). You need to use use the API to get more current stuff: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77174/data-from-the-stack-exchange-data-explorer-are-obsolete?rq=1